# ADO.NET command to script database creation

Tags: c#, ado.net, .net-2.0, sql-server-2000

Is there a SELECT command I can execute in ADO.NET to retrieve a script that will rebuild my database from scratch with empty tables? I'd like to be able to script the creation of the database itself, along with all the tables, views, and stored procedures and any relationships that exist between the tables. Also primary key and identity specifications.

I am using SQL Server 2000 and C# (.NET Framework 2.0).

Comment: You'd need to "build" your SQL statement(s) and then execute them via `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such SELECT command but you can use SQL Server Management Studio to generate such a script for you.

Context menu for a database in Object Explorer has `Script Database as` option that should do the trick for you. Then you could execute the resulting script from your program using standard `SqlCommand` objects.

Comment: Yeah I know about that. The database might change dynamically though and so I need a way to do this from a C# program, rather then from inside Enterprise Manager or SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may consider to build your database structure into the model (System databases / model). Then, each time you'll create a new database, you'll get all the stuff you need already inserted into your new database.

But be warned that this solution will create all the stuff for ALL the new databases created.